# Different Page Templates for Different Events (EVENTS CALENDAR PRO plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use different page templates for different events on EVENTS CALENDAR PRO plugin by Modern Tribe. I came up with this working code.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if (tribe_event_in_category('premier-event')) { 
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'template/custom.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    } 
    return $template;
}
```

Problem on Home page i have 15 events listen like this
[image]

When i add more events they go on second page (uses: tribe-events/default-template.php)
[image]

But if event to go on second page falls under category where i use custom template.Instead creating second page just loads full event and overrates tribe-events/default-template.php and loads template/custom.php .